# Detect file read/write from running a script

Tags: linux, shell, io

I will be getting some shell scripts that I, kind of, dont know what they will be doing. But I need to know what **I/O operations** the script performs (e.g. files they read/access,files they write, folders created...etc).

An example is using *strace* as follows:

**INPUT script:** `g++ -Wall a.cpp -o hello`

**I will run it as:** `sudo strace -f -e trace=open g++ -Wall a.cpp -o hello 2> output.txt`

**WHAT I WANT: ** output.txt will have the trace and which files had been accessed (a.cpp and b.h which is used in a.cpp, and output hello)

```
... 
[pid 13871] open("a.cpp", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3 
[pid 13871] open("b.h", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4 
... 
[pid 13874] open("hello", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
...
```

**Problem**

1- `strace` doesnt handle *pipe* so if I get a command like `mkdir d2 | cp *.c d2/` it will only detect the first command `mkdir d2`.

2- `strace` provide too much info which is fine but if something is more concrete that would be great!

I searched for other tools and utils, and most of them would list info for a *running process* and I **dont want that** since the script will be executed immediately and nothing would be in the process list in Ubuntu.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this in Ubuntu/Linux?

Comment: If you want to trace a pipe 'a | b' you could tell it to strace both commands: `sudo strace a | sudo strace b`. You might need to do some creative munging of the command line in order to make that happen, depending on how it's delivered to your program.

Comment: This would provide two separate traces, also I cant modify the script I was given

Comment: You couldn't concatenate the two traces?

Comment: Yes I can, but still I cant modify the script or parse it to detect the pipes. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)

> strace doesnt handle pipe so if I get a command like mkdir d2 | cp *.c
>   d2/ it will only detect the first command mkdir d2.

strace has two usefult options

```
 -f  Trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2) system call.
-ff  If the -o filename option is in effect, each processes trace is written to filename.pid where pid is the numeric process id of each process.
```

You can do this :

```
strace -f -o res.txt bash -c 'mkdir d2 | cp *.c d2/'
```

Or you can do this :

```
strace -ff -o res.txt bash -c 'mkdir d2 | cp *.c d2/'
```

2)

> strace provide too much info which is fine but if something is more concrete that would be great!

There is [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap) that "allows developers and administrators to write and reuse simple scripts to deeply examine the activities of a live Linux system". You can write your own scripts or you can use available scripts. [This is a script](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/general/regex.stp) from the SystemTap web site that detects opened files:

```
stap your_script.stp -c "your command"
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, running `strace bash -c '...'` will have the same problem that he has now: it will provide a trace on the files that `bash` opens, but it will not report on files opened by `mkdir` or `cp`.

Comment: @qwrrty, next week I will check it and answer you. But I remember I did `strace -f my_script.sh` and it worked. Anyway I will check it again. By the way: `-f` option of strace has this description: Trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2) system call (http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)